# How to move rigidbody object up or down smoothly in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, smoothing, rigid-bodies

I have start a project and I attached a rigidbody to my player for apply some force on it.So when I run my project then in `FixedUpdate()` function I apply a force on player to moving it in forward direction.So when I pressed leftarrow or rightarrow it perform 'tilt' means rotate it's wings.
But now I want to move my player up or down smoothly by pressing Uparrow or Downarrow,and when I press both uparrow and downarrow then it must be affect on player.
Here is my code.Please help me. :(

```
void FixedUpdate ()
{
  rb.AddForce(transform.forward *1000f);
  float movedir = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

  Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (movedir, 0.0f, 0.0f);
  rb.velocity = movement * movingspeed;
  rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0.0f, 0.0f, rb.velocity.x * -3f);//perform tilt


 if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow)) 
      { 
       //code for smoothly move up from current position to = current position + 2f 
      }

  if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow)) 
      { 
        //code for smoothly move down from current position to = current position - 2f 
      }


}
```

Comment: So you are almost done with your code.  You have your velocity. Change your coordinates with the amount of velocity * Time.Delta per Update

Comment: I am not professional and I don't know How to change coordinates can you  write some code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not really clear. Move `smoothly` could mean many things.

In general you should use [RigidBody.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) and [Rigidbody.MoveRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) to set a `Rigidbody`'s transforms instead of `rb.rotation` and `rb.position` in order to get "smooth" movements:

> Use Rigidbody.MovePosition to move a Rigidbody, complying with the Rigidbody's interpolation setting.
>
> If Rigidbody interpolation is enabled on the Rigidbody, calling Rigidbody.MovePosition results in a smooth transition between the two positions in any intermediate frames rendered. This should be used if you want to continuously move a rigidbody in each FixedUpdate.
>
> Set Rigidbody.position instead, if you want to teleport a rigidbody from one position to another, with no intermediate positions being rendered.

So as you can see depending on your settings using `Rigidbody.MovePosition` might already result in a "smooth" movement.

```
rb.MovePosition(transform.position + Vector3.up * 2.0f);
```

---

Also you use `Input.GetKeyDown` so it works like a trigger ... it is not called continously like `Input.GetKey`

If you want to move continously while the key stays pressed use e.g.

```
// set e.g. in the inspector
public float verticalMoveSpeed;

// ...

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) 
{ 
    rb.MovePosition(transform.position + Vector3.up * verticalMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) 
{ 
    rb.MovePosition(transform.position - Vector3.up * verticalMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

---

If you want to trigger the movement only with `GetKeyDown` instead you could also do something like e.g.

```
// set e.g. in the inspector
public float verticalMoveSpeed;

// ...

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) 
{ 
    StartCoroutine(MoveVertical(2.0f, verticalMoveSpeed));
} 
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)) 
{ 
    StartCoroutine(MoveVertical(-2.0f, verticalMoveSpeed));
}

// ...

private IEnumerator MoveVertical(float distance, float speed)
{
    var originalY = transform.position.y;
    var targetY = originalY + distance;

    var currentY = originalY; 
    do
    {     
        rb.MovePosition(new Vector 3(transform.position.x, currentY, transform.positiom.z);

        // Update currentY to the next Y position
        currentY = Mathf.Clamp(currentY + speed * Time.deltaTime, originalY, targetY);
        yield return null;
    }
    while(currentY < originalY);

    // make sure you didn't move to much on Y
    rb.MovePosition(new Vector3(transform.position.x, targetY, transform.position,z));
}
```

---

Than there are two options to prevent concurrent routines:

1. use a flag. This also prevents the routine from beeing interrupted/called twice/called concurrent

   ```
   privtae bool isMovingVertical;

   // ...

   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && !isMovingVertical ) 
   { 
       StartCoroutine(MoveVertical(2.0f, verticalMoveSpeed));
   } 
   else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) && !isMovingVertical ) 
   { 
       StartCoroutine(MoveVertical(-2.0f, verticalMoveSpeed));
   }

   // ...

   private IEnumerator MoveVertical(float distance, float speed)
   {
       isMovingVertical = true;

       // ...

       isMovingVertical = false;
   }
   ```
2. use `StopAllCoroutines` to interrupt a running routine (attention this might lead to "infinite" moves in one direction - at least without you preventing it with additional checks)

   ```
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) 
   { 
       StopAllCoroutines();
       StartCoroutine(MoveVertical(2.0f, verticalMoveSpeed));
   }

   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)) 
   { 
       StopAllCoroutines();
       StartCoroutine(MoveVertical(-2.0f, verticalMoveSpeed));
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks sir, my 90% problem has been solved from your answer. But there is a one more little bit issue , I want that when i press Uparrow then my player moving up and stop on a specific position.For example my player current position is 5 and I want to move it on 7 and when it reached on 7 then it should be stop moving up.

Comment: You could store the original `position.Y` value and than stop the routine if e.g. `originalY + 2.0f` or `originalY - 2.0f` is reached

Comment: Sir I have try but I don't stop it on exact position.Sometime it moves little bit up or down can you write some exact code for stopping it?

Comment: @FaisalmirzaMirza which solution did you choose?

Comment: I choose that solution in which you used startcoroutine().

Comment: The one with the `isMovingVertical` flag or using `StopAllCoroutines`?

Comment: 'isMovingVertical'

Comment: @derHuge Thanks sir for update your code now player move on exact position and stopped moving up, but it moves very fast.I want that when I press button then it should move smoothly to the end position.

Comment: You should be able to adjust that by changing the `verticalMoveSpeed` value e.g. in the inspector